# How to separate Title Page and Table of Content Page from knitr rmarkdown PDF?

Tags: r

Anyone have any idea how to separate Title Page and Table of Content page?
From this code:

```
---
title: "Title Page"
output: 
  pdf_document:
      toc: true
      number_sections: true
---
```

The few line of code above creates the Title and Table of Content, but there is no separation between the Title Cover Page and Table of Content.

I have found an alternative by adding latex symbols `\newpage` and `\tableofcontents`:

````
---
title: "Title Page"
output: 
    pdf_document
---

\centering
\raggedright
\newpage
\tableofcontents

# header 1
```{r}
summary(cars)
```

## header 2
```{r, echo=FALSE}
plot(cars)
```

## header 3
lore ipsum 

# header 4
lore ipsum
````

Is there a way without having to use latex `\newpage` and `\tableofcontents` and use `rmarkdown` somewhere in the following block:

```
---
title: "Title Page"
output: 
    pdf_document:
        toc: true
---
```

Answer (score 13):

I used a trifecta of latex files in the options under `includes:`

```
---
title: "Title Page"
output: 
  pdf_document:
  toc: true
    number_sections: true
  includes:
    in_header: latex/header.tex
    before_body: latex/before_body.tex
    after_body: latex/after_body.tex
---
```

The `before_body` file contain all of the options you would want AFTER the `\begin{document}` and the title options, but BEFORE you start writing the body of your document.  In that file, simply place a `\newline`, like so:

```
\newpage
```

**That's it!**  Nothing else in the `before_body.tex` file.  That should work.

Now, if only I could vertically center the title page...

Comment: If you're still looking for a way to vertically center the title, you can add vertical space by changing the title line to this: `title: \vspace{3in}Title Page` (based on code in [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/111588/4762) at the Tex Stack Exchange site).

Answer (score 3):

To avoid messing with `tex` files,

Turn off automatic toc insertion first in the YAML metadata.

```
---
title: "myTitle"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: 
  pdf_document:
    toc: no
    number_sections: true
urlcolor: blue
editor_options:
  chunk_output_type: console
documentclass: report
---
```

Then, wherever you want the toc to be in your document, add

````
```
{=latex}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\tableofcontents
```
````

You can then place this toc anywhere using latex macros such as `\newpage` or `\hfill\break` for example.

````
---
title: "myTitle"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: 
  pdf_document:
    toc: no
    number_sections: true
urlcolor: blue
editor_options:
  chunk_output_type: console
---
\newpage
```{=latex}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\tableofcontents
```
\newpage
````

[image: separated]

Note: `documentclass: report` in the metadata will automatically separate the toc from the title, but won't allow to separate it from the remainder of the document.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58025052/5224236)