# How can I separate the title page from the table of contents in a RMarkdown Word output?

Tags: r, ms-word, format, r-markdown

How can I separate the title page from the table of contents in a RMarkdown Word output? I've seen a lot on here about pdf and html output, but not much about Word. I've tried to use a little bit of LaTex, but it seems that most of that only works with pdf output, and the bit that does work with Word doesn't do what I'm looking for.

```
---
title: "Sample Title"
subtitle: "Sample Subtitle"
date: "April 8, 2020"
output:
  word_document:
    toc: yes
---

\newpage

# Header 1

sample text


## Header 2

more sample text


# Another Header 1

loren ipsum

## Another Header 2

foo bar
```

This just puts a blank page *after* the table of contents, not before. It feels like there is something simple that I'm missing.

Answer (score 1):

You may consider exploring the [officedown](https://github.com/davidgohel/officedown) package and its [block_toc](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/officedown/versions/0.0.5.003/topics/block_toc) function (together with `<!---CHUNK_PAGEBREAK--->` inline yaml):

```
---
title: "Sample Title"
subtitle: "Sample Subtitle"
date: "April 8, 2020"
output:
  officedown::rdocx_document
---

<!---CHUNK_PAGEBREAK--->

# Table of Contents    
`r officedown::block_toc(level = 5, style = NULL, separator = ";")`

<!---CHUNK_PAGEBREAK--->


# Header 1

sample text


## Header 2

more sample text


# Another Header 1

loren ipsum

## Another Header 2

foo bar
```

Or even simple, as discussed [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/rmarkdown-knit-word-toc-appers-first-page-when-i-want-it-in-the-second-page-after-front-page/52607/6):

```
<!---CHUNK_PAGEBREAK--->    
# Table of Contents
<!---BLOCK_TOC--->    
<!---CHUNK_PAGEBREAK--->
```

Answer (score 1):

To place the toc wherever needed without messing with `tex` files (here with a pdf output),

Turn off automatic toc insertion first in the YAML metadata.

```
---
title: "myTitle"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: 
  pdf_document:
    toc: no
    number_sections: true
urlcolor: blue
editor_options:
  chunk_output_type: console
documentclass: report
---
```

Then, wherever you want the toc to be in your document, add

````
```
{=latex}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\tableofcontents
```
````

You can then place this toc anywhere using latex macros such as `\newpage` or `\hfill\break` for example.

````
---
title: "myTitle"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: 
  pdf_document:
    toc: no
    number_sections: true
urlcolor: blue
editor_options:
  chunk_output_type: console
---
\newpage
```{=latex}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\tableofcontents
```
\newpage
````

Note: `documentclass: report` in the metadata will automatically separate the toc from the title, but won't allow to separate it from the remainder of the document.

[image: separated]

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58025052/5224236)

Answer (score 0):

I've had to add:
`r officer::run_pagebreak()`

before the first:
<!---CHUNK_PAGEBREAK--->

And another one after the last "CHUNK_PAGEBREAK" and that's it!